# is there MulDiv in C#?

Tags: c#

is there `MulDiv`

```
WINBASEAPI
int
WINAPI
MulDiv(
    _In_ int nNumber,
    _In_ int nNumerator,
    _In_ int nDenominator
    );
```

in C# or an equivalent to it?

or should I Implement it ?

Edit: with out PInvoking!!

Answer (score 7):

This is an enhancement to Hans Passant sugestion, but including the +0.5 rounding as per MSDN docs:

```
public static int MulDiv(int number, int numerator, int denominator)
{
    return (int)(((long)number * numerator + (denominator >> 1)) / denominator);
}
```

**Note:** This code uses right-shift operator to obtain top performance.

Answer (score 5):

This api function dates back to Windows version 3, a 16-bit version of Windows.  Quite possibly before, I'm not old enough.  Where it was a bit difficult to get a C compiler to multiply two 16-bit numbers (two ints), get a 32-bit intermediate result and divide by a 16-bit number to get a 16 bit result.  The operation was quite common, calculating a font size for example.

One of Microsoft's great burdens is that once they publish an api function, they have to maintain it *forever*, unless it is just grossly incompatible with necessary changes in the operating system.  Nothing gross about MulDiv(), the *int* arguments did however get an automatic boost to 32-bits, making the function just about entirely unnecessary.  But programs written for Win3 still compile, backcompat is sacred.

It was a bit of a mistake to burden the api with this, but the motivation was strong, pretty hard to cram a windowing system into 640 kilobytes.  Exposing stuff that's already there because the OS needs it really helps shaving off the bytes.  Other api functions like that are wprintf(), lstrcpyXxx(), etc.  Core C runtime functions and *still* available today, even maintained through the switch to Unicode.  An archeological record of Windows.

No point in pinvoking it, C# has no trouble doing this:

```
public static int MulDiv(int number, int numerator, int denominator) {
    return (int)(((long)number * numerator) / denominator);
}
```

Use the *checked* keyword if you want an overflow exception.

Comment: The reason to P/Invoke `MulDiv` is to get the same rounding and overflow behavior. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383718(v=VS.85).aspx for all the gory details.

Comment: Well, good thing I mentioned the *checked* keyword I guess :)  Catch and return -1, assuming that's really useful.  Magic numbers in a C api function are long obsolete as well.

Comment: Did you delete my question? I felt it was a legitimate question to ask why you felt MulDiv was a mistake despite the motivation for it.

Comment: Click the Ask Question button if you want to ask a question.

Comment: There is not enough content nor general relevance in my question to ask a new question on SO. Nor is my question fact-based. I'm asking for your opinion based on your answer here, which is why it's a comment to your answer here. Edit: If you're going to be grumpy and delete my comments, at least delete your own and fix your MulDiv to actually round. You're misusing your deletion privileges.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not available out-of-the-box. You need to do [PInvoke](http://pinvoke.net).

You can implement it yourself of course:

```
//truncation is unnecessary if you want to continue using a long
//the truncation can never overflow so it is unchecked
var result = unchecked((int)(nNumber * (long)nNumerator / nDenominator));
```

Comment: Nope I don't want to PInvoke it

Comment: I just asked ,so if there is already an implementation out there no need to waste time implementing one!

Comment: Sure. Fortunately, the CLR supports 64-bit ints so you can do it yourself in one line at full speed.

Comment: I don't think this will round the same as `MulDiv`.

Comment: @Gabe, can you be more specific? This is using 64bit intermediate values. It has full precision.

Comment: You have to truncate back to an int :)

Comment: Here's the documentation of MulDiv: "If the function succeeds, the return value is the result of the multiplication and division, rounded to the nearest integer. If the result is a positive half integer (ends in .5), it is rounded up. If the result is a negative half integer, it is rounded down.

If either an overflow occurred or nDenominator was 0, the return value is -1."

Comment: Damn it, I give up! Probably it's good enough for the OP anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it clear that you're going out of your way to handle the case where two 32-bit integers may yield a value larger than a 32-bit integer, you could use Math.BigMul, then just divide the result and cast it back to an integer. I see, as stated by other answers, .NET's support for 64-bit integers apparently provides all the benefits you'd need that MulDiv formerly would have (and then some).

```
int result = unchecked((int)(System.Math.BigMul(nNumber, nNumerator) / nDenominator));
```